# Chrome Dev Tools - Extra white space adding around page

Tags: html, css

When I open the Chrome Dev Tools and view my web page at different sizes, white space appears on the sides/bottom of the page. When I refresh the page, this extra space goes away.

This also happens when I change the size of the browser as well. The nav and the main stay in place, but the footer moves up from the bottom. Creating empty space.

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong w/ the CSS? Is there something I can do to make sure that all elements stay at their positions no matter what shape the browser changes to?

```css
/* 1440p */
@media only screen and (max-width: 2560px), screen and (max-height: 1440px) {

    body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    nav, main, section, footer {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    nav {
        background-color: #393e46;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
    
    #nav-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 775px; /* changes */
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #nav-links li {
        display: inline;
    }
    
    #nav-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #nav-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }
    
    #nav-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }
    
    main {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #main-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 775px; /* changes */
        padding: 18.05% 0%; /* changes */
    }
    
    /* controls the 'FGCPEDIA' masthead */
    #logo {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 150px; /* changes */
        margin: 16px 0px 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* controls the input field */
    input {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        border: 1px solid #f4f6ff;
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* removes the highlight from the form when selected */
    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }
    
    .footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 775px; /* changes */
    }
    
    #pre-footer-1 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-1-links {
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-1-links li {
        display: inline;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-1-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-1-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-2 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* controls the links in the pre-footer */
    #pre-footer-2-links {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-2-links li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0px 8px;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-2-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 15px;
        max-width: 100px;
        padding: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-2-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-2-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }
    
    footer {
        background-color: #222831;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* controls the copyright text */
    #copyright {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }

}

/* 1080p */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {

    body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
    
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    nav, main, section, footer {
        display: flex;
    }
    
    nav {
        background-color: #393e46;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }
    
    #nav-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 775px; /* changes */
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #nav-links li {
        display: inline;
    }
    
    #nav-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #nav-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }
    
    #nav-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }
    
    main {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #main-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 775px; /* changes */
        padding: 14.71% 0%;
    }
    
    /* controls the 'FGCPEDIA' masthead */
    #logo {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 150px; /* changes */
        margin: 16px 0px 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* controls the input field */
    input {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        border: 1px solid #f4f6ff;
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* removes the highlight from the form when selected */
    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }
    
    .footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 775px; /* changes */
    }
    
    #pre-footer-1 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-1-links {
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-1-links li {
        display: inline;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-1-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-1-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-2 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* controls the links in the pre-footer */
    #pre-footer-2-links {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-2-links li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0px 8px;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-2-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 15px;
        max-width: 100px;
        padding: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-2-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }
    
    #pre-footer-2-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }
    
    footer {
        background-color: #222831;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* controls the copyright text */
    #copyright {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }

}

/* iPad Pro */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    nav, main, section, footer {
        display: flex;
    }

    nav {
        background-color: #393e46;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }

    #nav-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 775px; /* changes */
        width: 100%;
    }

    #nav-links li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #nav-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #nav-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #nav-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }

    main {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #main-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 775px; /* changes */
        padding: 49% 0%;
    }

    /* controls the 'FGCPEDIA' masthead */
    #logo {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 150px; /* changes */
        margin: 16px 0px 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* controls the input field */
    input {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        border: 1px solid #f4f6ff;
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* removes the highlight from the form when selected */
    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

    .footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 775px; /* changes */
    }

    #pre-footer-1 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links {
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #pre-footer-2 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* controls the links in the pre-footer */
    #pre-footer-2-links {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0px 8px;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 15px;
        max-width: 100px;
        padding: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: #222831;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* controls the copyright text */
    #copyright {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

/* iPad */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    nav, main, section, footer {
        display: flex;
    }

    nav {
        background-color: #393e46;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }

    #nav-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 545px; /* changes */
        width: 100%;
    }

    #nav-links li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #nav-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #nav-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #nav-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }

    main {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #main-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 545px; /* changes */
        padding: 44.6% 0%;
    }

    /* controls the 'FGCPEDIA' masthead */
    #logo {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 106px; /* changes */
        margin: 16px 0px 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* controls the input field */
    input {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        border: 1px solid #f4f6ff;
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* removes the highlight from the form when selected */
    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

    .footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 545px; /* changes */
    }

    #pre-footer-1 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links {
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #pre-footer-2 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* controls the links in the pre-footer */
    #pre-footer-2-links {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0px 8px;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 15px;
        max-width: 100px;
        padding: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: #222831;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* controls the copyright text */
    #copyright {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

/* Surface Duo */
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    nav, main, section, footer {
        display: flex;
    }

    nav {
        background-color: #393e46;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }

    #nav-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 345px; /* changes */
        width: 100%;
    }

    #nav-links li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #nav-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #nav-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #nav-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }

    main {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #main-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 345px; /* changes */
        padding: 32% 0%;
    }

    /* controls the 'FGCPEDIA' masthead */
    #logo {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 67px; /* changes */
        margin: 16px 0px 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* controls the input field */
    input {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        border: 1px solid #f4f6ff;
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* removes the highlight from the form when selected */
    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

    .footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 345px; /* changes */
    }

    #pre-footer-1 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center; /* changes */
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links {
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #pre-footer-2 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* controls the links in the pre-footer */
    #pre-footer-2-links {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links li {
        display: inline; /* added */
        padding: 0px 8px; /* added */
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        display: inline;
        font-size: 15px;
        max-width: 100px;
        padding: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: #222831;
        width: 100%;
    }

    /* controls the copyright text */
    #copyright {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

/* Pixel 2, Pixel 2 XL, iPhone 6/7/8 Plus */
@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
    
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    nav, main, section, footer {
        display: flex;
    }

    nav {
        background-color: #393e46;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }

    #nav-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 245px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #nav-links li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #nav-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #nav-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #nav-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }

    main {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #main-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 245px;
        padding: 32.2% 0%; /* changes */
    }

    /* controls the 'FGCPEDIA' masthead */
    #logo {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 47px;
        margin: 16px 0px 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* controls the input field */
    input {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        border: 1px solid #f4f6ff;
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* removes the highlight from the form when selected */
    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

    .footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 245px;
    }

    #pre-footer-1 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links {
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #pre-footer-2 {
        background-color: #1e242c;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    /* controls the links in the pre-footer */
    #pre-footer-2-links {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        display: block;
        font-size: 15px;
        max-width: 100px;
        padding: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: #222831;
    }

    /* controls the copyright text */
    #copyright {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

/* Galaxy Fold, iPhone 5/SE, Moto G4, Galaxy S5, iPhone 6/7/8, iPhone X */
@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    
    body {
        font-family: Helvetica;
        margin: 0;
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    nav, main, section, footer {
        display: flex;
    }

    nav {
        background-color: #393e46;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }

    #nav-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 245px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #nav-links li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #nav-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #nav-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #nav-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }

    main {
        text-align: center;
    }

    #main-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 245px;
        padding: 32.4% 0%;
    }

    /* controls the 'FGCPEDIA' masthead */
    #logo {
        color: #ff0000;
        font-size: 47px;
        margin: 16px 0px 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* controls the input field */
    input {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        border: 1px solid #f4f6ff;
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    /* removes the highlight from the form when selected */
    input:focus, textarea:focus {
        outline: 0;
    }

    .footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 245px;
    }

    #pre-footer-1 {
        background-color: #222831;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links {
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #pre-footer-1-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #pre-footer-2 {
        background-color: #1e242c;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    /* controls the links in the pre-footer */
    #pre-footer-2-links {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-inline-start: 0px;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:link {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        display: block;
        font-size: 15px;
        max-width: 100px;
        padding: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:visited {
        color: #e5e5e5;
    }

    #pre-footer-2-links a:hover {
        color: #32e0c4;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: #222831;
    }

    /* controls the copyright text */
    #copyright {
        color: #e5e5e5;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 16px 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>title.com</title>
            <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>

        <body>

            <!-- nav section -->
            <nav id="nav">
                <div id="nav-container">

                    <!-- nav links -->
                    <ul id="nav-links">
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Sign Up |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Log In</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- main section -->
            <main>
                <div id="main-container">
                    
                    <!-- main row 1 -->
                    <div>
                        <h1 id="logo">BIG TITLE</h1>
                    </div>

                    <!-- main row 2 -->
                    <div>
                        <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </main>

            <!-- sub footer 1 section -->
            <section id="pre-footer-1">
                <div class="footer-container">

                    <!-- browse the dicitionary links -->
                    <ul id="pre-footer-1-links">
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/a.html" id="btd" style="text-transform: none;">Browse the Dictionary:</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/a.html">a |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/b.html">b |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/c.html">c |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/d.html">d |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/e.html">e |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/f.html">f |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/g.html">g |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/h.html">h |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/i.html">i |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/j.html">j |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/k.html">k |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/l.html">l |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/m.html">m |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/n.html">n |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/o.html">o |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/p.html">p |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/q.html">q |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/r.html">r |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/s.html">s |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/t.html">t |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/u.html">u |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/v.html">v |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/w.html">w |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/x.html">x |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/y.html">y |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/z.html">z</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!-- (4) pre-footer 2 section -->
            <section id="pre-footer-2">
                <div class="footer-container">

                    <!-- footer row 2 -->
                    <div>
                        <ul id="pre-footer-2-links">
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="pages/about_us.html">About Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="pages/contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="pages/terms_of_use.html">Disclaimer</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!-- (5) footer section -->
            <footer>
                <div class="footer-container">
                    <p id="copyright">&copy; 2020 copyright</p>
                </div>
            </footer>

            <!-- links to the js code -->
            <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I see you have margin:0; for body the extra space shouldn't be added.
But try this:

```
* { margin: 0; height: 100vh;}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps, the real question I need to ask is, 'How do I keep the footer at the bottom of the page without using the positioning property'?